# Query timeout exception reason?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, connection-timeout

I am really wondering how can I get a timeout exception in 2 seconds.

I have given the command timeout 400 secs and also not defined the connection timeout explicitly so it should consider the default connection timeout. There is no timeout in the ConnectionString as well. But 2 secs timeout is very very less. So my question is what else could be the reason?

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
> completion of the operation or the server is not responding

```
try
{
    Dapper.SqlMapper.Settings.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(400); //in secs
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    var data = connection.Query<MyClass>("MySP").ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogWrite(ex.ToStrin());
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedSec = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
    _logger.LogWrite("Execution time in Seconds: " + elapsedSec);
}
```

and this has failed only once not always.

Comment: Bad credentials, incorrect server or networking configuration on the server (such firewall).

Comment: @DanFriedman AS I have mentioned, it's working fine. but failed only once.

Answer (score -1):

I think LINQ is the issue. Calling ToList() method, you force LINQ to execute immediately and return actual results.
Try storing the result in some variable and then use LINQ on it.

```
var data = connection.Query<MyClass>("MySP"); 
Your variable = data.ToList();
```